# Apache with PHP: Can't find module?

Tags: php, postgresql, apache

trying to use LoadFile "C:/ProgramFiles/PostgreSQL/15/bin/libpq.dll" in the httpd.conf file.

I keep getting this from the error logs:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Apache Service
Date:          1/24/2023 6:46:09 PM
Event ID:      3299
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Cedric-PC
Description:
The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 542 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/ProgramFiles/PostgreSQL/15/bin/libpq.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.     .
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Apache Service" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">3299</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-01-24T23:46:09.4847737Z" />
    <EventRecordID>52674</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Cedric-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>The Apache service named</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>reported the following error:
&gt;&gt;&gt;</Data>
    <Data>httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 542 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/ProgramFiles/PostgreSQL/15/bin/libpq.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Everything is running x64. Apache is on VC15. PostgreSQL is 15.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.

EDIT:
Syntax error. Needed a space between "Program Files"...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things I noticed with the information you have provided.
Firstly, "C:/ProgramFiles/" is not a valid directory path.

It is typically "C:/Program Files/" or "C:/Program Files (x86)/"
I recommend copy/paste the folder path from the Windows explorer directory when you need to specify an absolute path like this.

Second, with Apache, you cannot load any arbitrary DLL file.
It must be a compiled library that is built for Apache, typically "mod_" will always be in it's name.

Finally,
Since the tag php is part of your post, I will assume that is what your web application is written in.
Normally, you would load an extension within php, in the php.ini file.

Look for your php.ini file within the installation directory.
Find the lines
`extension=php_pgsql.dll`
`extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`

Uncomment one, or both of them. Which ever fits your needs.
You may need to direct your PATH environment variable to the location where libpq.dll is located to have php find it.

I have worked in IT my entire life, and have been using Apache and php for most of that time.

Best of luck.